# How to Mentioned Leavetype in employee attendance register?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have two tables. One is employee attendance and second one is Employee Leave.

- Employee attendance col( Empid,INTIME,OUTTIME,Status)
- Employee Leave   col(Empid,StartDate,Endate,leavetype(PL,CL,SL))

I have created pivot table in which present, absent and HD mentioned and created another separate query for sum of row (Present ,absent and HD) From EmployeeAttendance Table.

===Sum query===

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'P' THEN 1  
WHEN status = 'HD' THEN 0.5 WHEN status = 'A' THEN 0 END) AS [T.P],  
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1 WHEN status = 'HD' THEN 0.5 END) AS [A],  
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'P' THEN 1  
WHEN status = 'HD' THEN 1 WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS [TDay ]  
FROM EmployeesAttendance  
--WHERE (ReportingDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate)  
GROUP BY EmpID
```

===Pivot Table ===

for converting col into row

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReportingDate INTO #Dates  
FROM EmployeesAttendance  
ORDER BY ReportingDate  
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(4000)  
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(DAY, ReportingDate), 112)  
+ ']','[' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(DAY, ReportingDate), 112) + ']')  
FROM #Dates  
ORDER BY ReportingDate  
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(4000) =  
N'SELECT *  
FROM (SElECT EmployeeDetails.EmpID,EmployeeDetails.EmpName,EmployeesAttendance.Status,  
DATEPART(DAY, EmployeesAttendance.ReportingDate)as DDate  
FROM EmployeesAttendance Inner Join EmployeeDetails on EmployeesAttendance.EmpID=EmployeeDetails.Empid )  
emp  
PIVOT (MAX(Status) FOR DDate IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat
```

-- Executing the query
   EXEC(@qry)

I want this Employee attendance Register.

```
Date   1  2  3  4   5   Total  Absent Present Leave 
Emp1   P  P  A  PL  P    5       1      3      1
Emp2   Cl  pl A  PL  P    5       1      2      2
```

Now I want to merge above bother query of Sum and Pivot, also mentioned leave type in attendance register if employee availed leaves From 01-01-2019 to 02-01-2019 Noofdays equal to 2 for (emp2)

Comment: bc i am also working o n C#

Comment: This kind of task can be better handled in either SSRS, RDLC report or in Crystal Report.